# Can't access the directory /etc/ppp/peers?

Tags: permissions, sudo, cd-command

I want to read some configuration file. The problem is that I can't move in the folder `peers` and typing the command *ls -l*, I see this permission's record:

```
drwxr-s--- root dip ...
```

I never seen that `s`, and reading on the web now I know that's the gid bit. Also the name of the group is unusual, normally I read root here.

When I try:

```
sudo cd ./peers
```

I get an error because the cd command is not found.

Why can't I move in this directory as super user? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter the shell as root using

```
sudo su
```

Then you'll be able to

```
cd /etc/ppp/peers
```

---

Alternatively you could just

```
sudo ls -l /etc/ppp/peers
```